# How to show only first three images in list with css nth-child(-n+3)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Basicly this is a news feed with 10 items in a list. First 3 articles will show an image associated with the article and the following entries should hide the images.

I do not wish to put extra rules in the php to achieve this. I want to do it with CSS `nth-child` or similar.

This is the `CSS`

```
.container ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.articlePhoto {
    display: none;
}

.container li:nth-child(-n+3) {
    display: block;
}
```

This is the `HTML`

```
<div class='container'>
    <ul>

        <li class='articleContainer'>
            <div class='articlePhoto'>
                <img
                    class='img-fluid rounded'
                    src='https://via.placeholder.com/350x150'
                    alt='Lorem ipsum'
                >
            </div>
            <div>
                <a
                    class='categoryList'
                    href='?ncid=1004&naid=10000&nacid=1000'
                    title='Lorem ipsum'
                >Lorem ipsum</a>
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem ipsum
                <hr>
                 friday, 17 august, 2018
                <hr>
                Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsum, Lorem ipsum
            </div>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

This CSS is just the last one I tried before I gave up. I have tried lots of combinations that does not do what I want and I can't figure out why it does not work. This current combination show no pictures at all.

Others I've tried with no luck:
`.container li :nth-child(-n+3) img`,
`.container img:nth-child(-n+3)`,
`ul:nth-child(-n+3) img`

and on and on and on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using a [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

```
.articleContainer:nth-child(3) ~ .articleContainer img {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: I select this answer because it doesn't matter if I use a `<ul>` or `<div>`. It works with both. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the structure, but if it is something like this?

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li class="articleContainer">
          <div class="articlePhoto"><img src.../></div>
          article 1 content...
        </li>
        <li class="articleContainer">
          <div class="articlePhoto"><img src.../></div>
          article 2 content...
        </li>
        <li class="articleContainer">
          <div class="articlePhoto"><img src.../></div>          
          article 3 content...
        </li>
        <li class="articleContainer">
          <div class="articlePhoto"><img src.../></div>          
          article 3 content...
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

U could use this CSS 2 to hide images for articles 4+:

```
.container li + li + li + li .articlePhoto { display: none }
```

Or if you want to use CSS 3 :nth-child:

```
.container li:nth-child(n+4) .articlePhoto { display: none }
```